# How to add new Dynamic Web API to ABP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-boilerplate

I want to add new API to ASP.NET Boilerplate's template for ASP.NET Core.

I've tried to make it, but I always get response code 500 on Swagger. How can I add new API?

[image: Error 500 on Swagger]

## Update

> Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Can't create component 'CityInfo.Models.TempatManager' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'CityInfo.Models.TempatManager' is waiting for the following dependencies: - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[CityInfo.Models.Tempat, CityInfo.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

Comment: This is just a wall of code and a wish list, what is the question? Where are you having a problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Check the error in Logs.txt.

Comment: the question is, How to add new api in asp boilerplate? that's code it's my effort.

Comment: Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Can't create component 'CityInfo.Models.TempatManager' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

@aaron

Comment: Which dependencies?

Comment: 'CityInfo.Models.TempatManager' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[CityInfo.Models.Tempat, CityInfo.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

@aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CityInfo.Models.TempatManager** is waiting for **CityInfo.Models.Tempat** which was not registered.

So what you have to do; 
Inherit Tempat from Entity or FullAuditedEntity

```
public class Tempat  : FullAuditedEntity
{
     //.....
}
```

and add this to your DbContext

```
public virtual DbSet<Tempat> Tempats { get; set; }
```

---

Further info, read: 
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entities

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class (Tempat) has probably not been added to your DbContext.

Just add the following property to your DbContext class and you should be good to go:

`public virtual IDbSet<CityInfo.Models.Tempat> Tempat { get; set; }`